# Tastypie or django-rest-framework for django in existing versions

Tags: django, rest, tastypie, django-rest-framework

Both of them certainly were great some time ago, there were similar topics proving that, however we had many updates both on django and framework sides. So the question is:

which one to choose now?

Comment: also see this thread on the topic
[what-are-the-differences-between-django-tastypie-and-djangorestframework][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303313/what-are-the-differences-between-django-tastypie-and-djangorestframework

Comment: As it is, this is not a good question for SO: both projects are great, and which one you pick - without very explicit requirements - come down as a personal preference. Which is not what SO is for! Please see the SO FAQ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really broad. I haven't used django-rest-framework for nothing big. Altough I use Tastypie heavily everyday for a big API. And it was really good.

We were able to plug our own custom authentication mechanism, that ended up working pretty well. Also, I needed to use complex schema types (GPX, and TCX formats) and it was really easy to make those work.

As a summary, Tastypie is really easy to extend. Also, it's really easy to start. With a couple of lines you can get a working API.

It has a good support of HATEOAS and a great error handling feature. It uses pretty well HTTP status codes too.

As a final thought, both seem to be heavily developed (both have commits in the last couple of days).

It's up to you to choose accordingly to your needs.

Comment: You are right, I should be more precise. Anyway, it seem tastypie is perfect for me, as I just need to show that there is an api and I can communicate with android - nothing fancy then. Thank you very much.
Actualy probably the most complicated thing will be to send password as secure as possible, so I hope it is not hard to go for it.

Comment: Hope it helps. Tastypie is great. Use SSL and you'll have the password thing covered.

Comment: great! so that is all what I need. Awesome, thank you very much and have a nice day! Oh and you helped me second time - thank you:)