# tastypie difficulties

Tags: tastypie, django-rest-framework

For me, the toughest part of making app was finding ways to make tastypie work in undocumented area.

I'm listing stuff I find it hard about tastypie below.. (It's been a few month I actively worked with tastypie-related code. so my description might not be perfect)

It's mostly about related-field management.

1. Suppose resource_a has related field resource_b.
   When user create a resource_a_instance with resource_b_data,
   if resource_b_data is dictionary data, tastypie creates resource_b_instance and creates resource_a_instance. (I find this is magical.. We can only control 'related_name' to something.)
   if resource_b_data is resource_uri, tastypie uses it as foreign key.

   So either, client has to send resource_uri only for resource_b, or server has to modify the resource_b_data.
2. when client sends 'patch', tastypie actually get all the fields to construct the corresponding object, and do 'put'.  and it has to read related fields as well iirc.

   I encountered a bug dealing with image field update.
   https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/1018
   tastypie dehydrates and uses it to update the object, dehydrating image-field gives url not the path and it causes the problem.
   dehydrate is for preparing data for user consumption, and it's used for updating data... I guess it's a big problem.
3. I'd like to send subset of defined fields per requests, but it doesn't seem to be there's a cleaner way.
4. How do I paginate the many-end of a related field? (with the pagination related meta field included)
5. `#3, #4` are just examples, when I have to do something beyond the doc, it's hard to know how to proceed. I guess you have to read the code carefully..

I hope if someone could show how the above problems are solved in django-rest-framework world as well.
I've seen comments about django-rest-framework having well-thought-out structure and wonder if it indeed offer easier solution on above problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303313/what-are-the-differences-between-django-tastypie-and-djangorestframework.. check this link

Comment: Could you detail the moments where you feeled stuck with Tastypie? I'm not sure Tastypie has so much magic spots.. What do mean exactly?

Comment: Fixed wording for it not to be overly opinion-based