# REST API in Python / Django

Tags: python, django, api, rest

I am building an iPhone application that communicates with an API on the backend. At the moment, the API is written in Django (by someone else than me) and we are considering rewriting it from scratch. The only real requirements that we have are that the API must be fully REST-full and versioned. The authentication/authorization scheme is not a priority at the moment (as in OAuth is not required, we can do with basic authentication).

I come from a Ruby/Rails background and I do not know python at all.

So my question is:

**Is there any libraries for Django that would make it easy to build rapidly such an API?**

I was thinking of tools like [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape), [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) or even [sinatra](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra) (as a rails middleware maybe).

I know about [flask](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask), but can it be integrated to Django?

Answer (score 2):

[TastyPie](http://tastypieapi.org/) and [Django REST framework](http://django-rest-framework.org) are your best options for Django.

Personally I think TastyPie is particularly good at choosing a default set of conventions for you and getting you up and running quickly, and Django REST framework is particularly good in it's layered design, making it easy to customise your API exactly how you need it to be.

Both have extensive documentation and lots of community support.  (I'm not sure what @timus2001's lack of documentation comment is based on.)

You absolutely shouldn't use Piston as it's been unmaintained for a long time now.  (Last release was 2011

See also [this similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303313/what-are-the-differences-between-django-tastypie-and-djangorestframework), and Daniel Greenfeld's [take on this](http://pydanny.com/choosing-an-api-framework-for-django.html) from back in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

**Django Piston** 
https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation

Advantages - Easy to get setup and started.  Works well if you use the default configuration.
Disadvantages -  implementing custom serialization methods is tough.

**Django REST Framework** http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Advantages -simple  learning curve

Disadvantages - Seems to have the least documentation out of the the three.

**TastyPie** http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Advantages - Best name out of the three options.  Seems to have the most features for implementing customized serialization and tying into non-ORM sources of data.

throttling,permissions,authentication  are simpler

Disadvantages - The reason I avoided TastyPie the first time around is it seemed too complex for my needs.  TastyPie might be overkill for simple use cases.

Comment: drf also has throttling, permissions and authentication. I haven't tried the others, but I've had no problems using drf even when I had to implement more advanced stuff

Comment: TastyPie looks really interesting. However, looking at the README, it looks like JSON responses are not supported (which is a problem) and there is no mention of Hypermedia APIs/content-types (I am specifically interested in [json:api](http://jsonapi.org)).